# Пагинация на php mvc

Tags: php, mvc

Не могу реализовать пагинацыю в паттерне mvc.Например  у меня есть контролер "**News**" в нем action "**category($id)**" в нем я получаю список новостей одной категории.В url выводится **http://News/category/4**. Вопрос как реализвать пагинацию если мне нужно добавить второй параметер,  $page , а в mvc а у меня структура http://controller/action/parameter

```
$controllerName = 'Controller\\' . $controller . 'Controller';
$controllerObj = new $controllerName;
$controllerObj->$action($param);
```

Comment: добавь `GET` параметр `page` например..... `http://News/category/4?page=666`

Comment: вы планируете что у вас все приложение будет иметь только один параметр всегда, или что значит `controller/action/parameter` ?

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий про единственный параметр совершенно справедлив, либо делайте правила парсинга url, либо передавайте все параметры, которые идут после указания action. Но это к теме не относится.

Далее смотрите в контроллере, если есть параметр GET['page'] а может еще и pageSize, либо по дефолту его задайте, то при создании моделей в запрос добавляете

```
LIMIT $page * $pageSize - $pageSize, $pageSize
```

Естественно добавляете валидацию, подготовительный запрос и все такое.